# Display a waiting gif during a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I write a script to get a text file, to modify this texter file and then I import the file in our software.
The problem is that the import of the file is very slow (just this part of the script could take more than 1 minute sometime).
I would like to display a waiting gif during this process, so the user can see that the process is running, and he need to wait.

Some precision:
 - It's only a javascript file with no html page
 - The script is launched with a button in our software and I have access to ActiveXObject if necessary

Here is a sample code :

```
function importFec()
{
    var iOpenDlg = 1;
    var sPath = "Deskop";
    var sTypes = "Fichier Texte (*.txt)|*.txt";
    var sExt = "txt";
    //Allow me to select a file in Windows
    cheminFEC = fileDialog(iOpenDlg, sPath, sTypes, sExt);

    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var ForReading = 1;
    var f1 = fso.OpenTextFile(cheminFEC, ForReading);
    var texte = f1.ReadAll();

    var tableauFEC = [];
    var tableauTest = [];
    tableauFEC = texte.split(/\r\n/);
    tableauTest = tableauFEC[0].split("\t");
    var delimiter = "\t";
    if (tableauTest.length == 1)
    {
        tableauTest = tableauFEC[0].split("|");
        var delimiter = "|";
    }
    var nbColonne = tableauTest.length;
    for (var i=0;i<tableauFEC.length;i++)
    {
        var tab = tableauFEC[i].split(delimiter);
        tableauFEC[i] = new Array(25);
        for (var j=0;j<nbColonne;j++)
        {
             tableauFEC[i][j] = tab[j];
         }
    }

    //Make some change in the table to adapt my texte file
    //Then create a new texte file C:\\FichierFEC\\FECModifie.txt
    createNewFEC(tableauFEC);

    var cwfConfiguration = Application.ApplicationInfo("ProgramPath")+"\\Library\\ImportFEC\\ImportFEC23032017.vgl"
    var oImport = Import(ipASCII)
    oImport.ImportComponents = CWImportComponents.icGeneralLedger
    oImport.ASCIILayoutFile = cwfConfiguration
    oImport.ASCIIDataFile = "C:\\FichierFEC\\FECModifie.txt"
    //This is the function which take a long moment to execute
    oImport.RunImport()

}
```

Thanks for your answer and explanation

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough detail here... but is there a place where importFec is called? Before you call that, can you display an animated GIF, then when control is returned after the function call kill the image?

Comment: I typically just create a div with my .gif inside it and set its display to none on initial load, when doing the process, set display to block, then on process complete set its display back to none.

Comment: @DragonYen Yes, the function is called in the script. The idea is to display a GIF just before I call the function. The problem I have is that I don't know how I can display the gif

Comment: @RyanWilson I don't have an html page. It's just a script file. So I don't have the solution to use a div

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly found another solution.
At the beggining of my script, I launch a .hta file with a GIF and a small texte.
At the end of my script, I close the .hta file

Thanks

Comment: You could also use FontAwesome fa-spinner / fa-spin